# Auto complete for careers "Where do you want to work?" field is broken/annoying

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

The auto complete field for "Where do you want to work?" is very annoying. I want to enter "1 Infinite Loop" but the auto complete keeps changing it to "Loop, Illinois, United States". I tried to work around it by disabling javascript during the blur event but this doesn't work because the autocomplete is also performed server side.

Also, it's not possible to submit the form when javascript was disabled.

Comment: This is because they don't want Apple Employees. ;)

Comment: I wanted to enter "Utopia Planitia, Mars" but that wasn't accepted either. THE NERVE!

Comment: @Chacha102: I agree it's annoying, but we don't need the tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We accept a large set of location names on careers (towns, cities, states, countries and continents), but we don't accept exact addresses.  If you'd like to work at 1 Infinite Loop, you should just enter "Cupertino, CA" (we have a [number](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs/7897) [of](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs/7088) [job](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs/7067) listings at Apple if you'd like to apply).

As for turning off javascript...we don't recommend it.