# Wrong Country and Province

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, location

I've tried to change it a few times, but my profile keeps defaults to IN, United States. It doesn't save the postal code and doesn't seem to want to accept NL, Canada.

Comment: Possibly related to [the automatic location matcher](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88217)? EDIT: maybe not... the Yahoo! API [matches "NL, Canada" to Newfoundland and Labrador](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=NL,%20Canada).

Comment: Do you mean IN (Indiana) or IL (Illinois)? The latter has come up several times; it seems to be a default when the system can't figure out your location: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61008, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109350, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109181, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67098

Comment: It's coming up as the former (IN). Could be postal code related as I tried that first which is when it decided I'm in IN, United States.

Comment: Looking into it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up. This should be resolved, would you try entering your location again?